# C#/XML: 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants'

Tags: c#, xml, definition

I just received an error a while ago from this code:

```
private void ShowXMLDatatoRTB() {
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("XMLFile.xml");

var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
        select new
            {
                Name = person.Element("Name").Value,
                    City = person.Element("City").Value,
                Age = person.Element("Age").Value,
            };

richTextBox1.Text = "";
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Name: " + person.Name + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "City: " + person.City + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Age: " + person.Age + "\n\n";
    }

if (richTextBox1.Text == "")
            richTextBox1.Text = "No Results."; }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to switch from XmlDocument to XDocument.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) but actually using the old school DOM API. You need to add references to `System.XML` and `System.Xml.Linq` and use `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
```

intead of

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); `
```